# DRIVE API - Page break in converted HTML document

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a page break on an uploaded file created after a HTML document.

When I download a Drive document as a HTML file, the page break is created with a `<hr style="page-break-before:always;display:none;">` element. So I tried copying that but it is transformed into a simple `<hr>` when it is uploaded.

```
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('Procesodecontroldeproducto.html');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType( 'text/html');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
    'data' => '<p>This is the first page</p><hr style="page-break-before:always;display:none;"><p>This should be on the second page</p>',
    'mimeType' => 'text/html',
    'convert' => true
));
```

My question is: Is there any way to create a page break when converting a HTML document to a  drive doc?

Comment: I suspect not directly. My guess is that you'd have better luck converting your HTML to document format such as docx or odt and uploading that.

Comment: I was thinking on that but I wanted to know if there was a solution for HTML-to-document conversion.

Comment: Yup, the same happens to me when I try to use insertPageBreak https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertpagebreakrequest